# Load Balancing virtual machines via Service Management API - MS Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I found the below article to create a virtual machine and load balance with an existing virtual machine.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/?_sm_au_=iVVNR02FVsMFjVB3

But how can the same be done via Service Management API.

The  related tags i found in the POST request to create a VM are ,

LoadBalancedEndpointSetName, LoadBalancerProbe

Where do I get started ? How do i connect two virtual machine via API ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is from a [post](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/) on Virtual Machines by Michael Washam, however the idea is the same for teh Windows Azure SErvice management REST API:

> A load balanced set is simply configuring the same endpoint on
>   multiple VMs and setting another property called the
>   “LoadBalancedEndpointSetName (or LBSetName in PowerShell) with a
>   common name to group the endpoints together. This functionality is
>   abstracted away within the Windows Azure management portal but it is
>   good to go into in detail because from the command line you can have
>   much more control over the load balancer by using custom health
>   probes.

As Michael Washam points out you just need to use the same endpoint for the two Virtual Machines and provide the same LoadBalancedEndpointSetName to the [Create Virtual Machine Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157194) operation.

Comment: Hi Neil .. if this is the case even though i give the same endpoint to two virtual machines under the same cloud service !! How will i be able to connect the two virtual machines ?

Comment: You don't load balance SSH or RDP endpoints. You give a different public endpoint for SSH or RDP to each virtual machine so that you can connect individually to them.

Comment: I configured the same LoadBalancedEndpointSetName for two virtual machines under the same cloud service !!! But when i looked in the portal the load balanced option is "no" ... what else i need to do ..